# Disabling a checkbox in a html table cell in row on checking other check box other cell in the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable the check box in a html table cell when other check box is checked in the same row in MVC.

The controller code is given below:

```
<table id='myTable1'>
<th>Buy</th>

<th>Sell</th>

<tbody>

@foreach (var item in Model)

 {
<td>
<input id="assignChkBx" name="chk" type="checkbox" value="@item.itemId">
</td>

 <td>
<input id="Buy" name="BuyPO" type="checkbox"  value="@item.itemId"/>
</td>`

}

</tbody>


</table>
```

I want to disable sell when I select, buy and vice versa.. Pls help... TIA..

Comment: I want something like this  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/na8qL/) but with in a table.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using radio buttons instead. If you give them the same name (but different IDs) they will automatically check and uncheck each other.

Comment: No,I need to use check boxes so that i can select multiple records at a time and approve them all at once